# Bootstrap not getting install through command prompt for angular 6 project

Tags: angular6

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@3.4.0 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.3.1 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.14.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.7 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.7: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ bootstrap@4.3.1
updated 1 package and audited 40445 packages in 18.647s
found 2 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

After giving command for installing bootstrap, I am getting this. And I have checked in node modules folder also, but it is not installed. Can anyone please help me

Comment: did you install the dependencies listed in the `WARN` messages? (i.e. jquery, popper, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manually you can add into the package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {

"bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
```

},

into the package.json file you can find dependencies then add this thing.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem just install those packages manually using npm:

```
npm install ajv

npm install jquery

npm install popper.js
```

now you already have all needed packages.

---

To run boostrap properly make also those steps:

1. Open angular.json file and edit scripts section by adding jquery popper and bootstrap scripts as below:

> "scripts": [ "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
>   "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
>   "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js" ]

2. Open src/styles.css file and add import of boostrap css:

> @import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';